# MeteorJS I can't seem to ever get a property of an object from the server

Tags: javascript, web-applications, meteor, publish-subscribe

Hey guys I have been having a ton of problems with meteorJS, because I can't seem to ever access the properties of anything client side when I subscribe to the publication on the server side. I have a collection with a "daily event" for my users that I'm going to be trying to publish to the client side. But for some reason it's undefined on the client side, even though I can do a console.log on the server side and it works fine.

Here's the code:

```
Client side:

communityEvents = new Mongo.Collection("communityEvents");
Meteor.subscribe('communityEventsPub');
Template.communityEvent.helpers({
    type: function(){

        todaysEvent = communityEvents.find().fetch();
        console.log("this is the event " + todaysEvent["type"]);
        return todaysEvent.type;
    },
    event: function(){

        todaysEvent = communityEvents.find().fetch();
        return todaysEvent.event;
    }
});

Server Side:

communityEvents = new Mongo.Collection("communityEvents");
Meteor.publish("communityEventsPub", function(){
    console.log(moment().format('l'));
    console.log(communityEvents.find({date:moment().format('l')}).fetch());
    return communityEvents.find({date:moment().format('l')});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) returns an array. In your helpers you'd need to do something like:

```
var todaysEvent = communityEvents.find().fetch()[0];
```

or

```
var todaysEvent = communityEvents.findOne();
```

You can easily test a publication by opening your browser console and doing a `fetch` like so:

```
communityEvents.find().fetch()
```

Which will return an array (hopefully) that you can examine.

Comment: Holy crap, thank you so much! That worked. Could you please explain to me what exactly a cursor is? I have heard the term before, and even after reading about the fetch function and the cursors description on the docs page you linked, I still don't get it.

Comment: It's more than I can explain in a comment. Have a look at [this video](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-how-do-client-cursors-work) for an in-depth examination of cursors.